# Schematic review - Darlington transistor seems to stay saturated in rare cases

Tags: circuit-design

This question is related to a circuit that was designed about 5 or 6 years ago. We observed some failures over the years, where the resistor R25 gets very hot (beyond 120°C).

I was not involved in the design back at the time and are somewhat unsure/skeptical about the circuit function and how to debug the issue.

**Background:**

The schematic is part of the [physical bus layer implementation of a M-Bus Master device](http://www.m-bus.com/mbusdoc/md4.php). The relevant information (to this question) from that link is:

> The transfer of bits from master to slave is accomplished by means of voltage level shifts. A logical "1" (Mark) corresponds to a nominal voltage of +36 V at the output of the bus driver (repeater), which is a part of the master; when a logical "0" (Space) is sent, the repeater reduces the bus voltage by 12 V to a nominal +24 V at its output.

**Basic functional description (refer to schematic):**

(Correct me if something seems to make no sense. As I mentioned I did not design the circuit and interpret it the way I think it works.)

- The voltage on MBUSOUT is toggled between 24V and 36V synchronously to the TXD1 signal that comes from a micro controller USART
- The "trick" to toggle the voltage levels between 24/36V are the z-diodes D3 and D4. Those diodes offset the voltage reference of the regulator IC5 (6V output) by either 18V (Q4 is off) or 30V (Q4 is on).
- The function of Q5 is (as far as I assume, its not properly documented :/) to speed up the edge transitions (36V->24V) by discharging the parasitic bus capacitance (bus can be several hundred meter long) through R25.
- D5 prevents Q5 from switching when the bus is idle.
- Q5 switches on when bus voltage changes from 36V->24V because Vbe(36V-24V-5.6V )

**Issue / questions:**

- In rare cases, R25 gets very hot, so Q5 obviously does not switch off.
- We suspect the problem is related to temperature (Q5? D5? IC5?). Probably thermal runaway?
- I believe it may be a problem with an unstable operating point of Q5?
- Shouldn't the current through Q5 be limited by a base resistor?

Any feedback and suggestions for improvements are welcome.

[image]

Comment: What about presenting some measurements and compare working condition with failure condition?

Comment: @PlasmaHH: We are currently trying to reproduce the issue under test conditions. It only occurs rarely in the field.

Comment: @Rev1.0 try some heat (a hot air tool) on those zeners. I also agree with you that you would expect Q5 to have a base resistor. I wonder if Q5 is being driven so far into saturation that it is too slow to turn off.

Comment: An emitter follower does not need a base resistor.

Comment: @CL. If both input and output of an emitter follower are low-impedance points then you **do** need a (base) resistor to prevent excess current flow through the base. In a proper design that extra current should flow through the collector to the emitter. Not through the base.

Comment: @SteveG: We are on it. We also compared some measurements with a 10k base resistor with the original ones and the turn off time is much shorter now. There seems to be a dependency between temperature (not sure which component makes the difference, its hard to thermally isolate them) and turn off time of the transistor (the hotter, the longer it takes).

Comment: This is just a half of the m-bus master, you have ommited the other components, so this schematics isn't complete. What if the problem is in some other transitor, resitor...hooked parallel on this circuit?

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem with this circuit is that **1)** zenerdiodes are leaky when the reverse voltage is below their zener voltage and **2)** the darlington Q5 only needs very little base current to turn on.

The leakage currents of those zener diodes might be enough to turn on Q5 when it is expected to be off.

Maybe you can solve this by adding a resistor between base and emitter of Q5. I'd start with a 100k resistor. Then the leakage from the zeners has to be large enough to make enough voltage across this resistor.

You're also right about the lack of a (current limiting) (base) resistor in the path BE of Q5 - D5 - D3 - D4. Since the base current of Q5 should be small (when operated properly, I mean, why use a Darlington if not for the small base current ??) there should be no problem adding a base series resistor to Q5.

Comment: I would also note that both the zener / avalanche voltage and leakage currents in the zeners is thermally dependent.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. We are now able to reproduce the problem using a hot air blower. The transistor takes longer to switch off, the warmer it gets. A base-emitter resistor did not seem to help. However a 1k base resistor improved the situation, while a 10k base resistor seems to cure the runaway issue. I am still not comfortable with how it looks on the oscilloscope though.

Comment: Regarding the zener leakage, wouldn't the base resistor alone correct that?

Comment: No, assume a small leakage current through D5, if you add a resistor in series with it the current still flows through the base of Q5. You want a way to give that current a different path **around** the base of Q5. For a 5 uA leakage current a 100 K resistor between Base and Emitter of Q5 will do that as 5 uA * 100 k ohm = 0.5 V, that is to small to open the BE junctions of Q5 (it's a darlington, it would need more than 1 V) so the current will go through the 100 k ohm resistor and not the BE of Q5, which is what we want.